# How could I refactor these variants to be used inside of a useAnimate hook?

Tags: reactjs, framer-motion

I'm currently working on my portfolio redesign using React, TypeScript, Tailwind CSS, and Framer Motion. What I'm trying to do is have one animation trigger and then when it's done trigger the next animation. I'm looking to have the oneLiner animations trigger and then the nav links animation trigger.

This example works, but when I try to incorporate the animations from the letter variant and itemVariants, delay, and staggerChildren into the mix I get "no overload matches this call" and the only animation that triggers is it blinks twice and that's all.

Slightly working basic example -

```
  const [scope, animate] = useAnimate();

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleAnimations = async () => {
      await animate(
        '#sentence',
        {
          opacity: [0, 1],
        },
        { duration: 2, ease: 'easeInOut' }
      );
      await animate(
        'li',
        { opacity: [0, 1] },
        { duration: 2, ease: 'easeInOut' }
      );
    };
    handleAnimations();
  });
```

What I'm currently animating -

```
<nav
  ref={scope}
  className='flex flex-col md:flex-row item-center justify-center w-full gap-2 p-4 overflow-hidden'
>
  <motion.div
    id='sentence'
    className='w-full md:w-2/5 flex items-center font-serif tracking-normal sm:tracking-wide text-xl px-4'
    variants={sentence}
    initial='hidden'
    animate='visible'
  >
    <span className='sr-only'>{oneLiner}</span>
    {oneLiner.split('').map((char, index) => (
      <motion.span
        id='letter'
        key={`${char} - ${index}`}
        variants={letter}
      >
        {char === ' ' ? '\u00A0' : char}
      </motion.span>
    ))}
  </motion.div>
  <motion.ul
    className='w-full md:w-3/5  gap-8 flex items-center justify-end'
    variants={containerVariants}
    initial='hidden'
    animate='visible'
  >
    <motion.li
      className='w-56 bg-silver text-black  flex items-center justify-center relative text-4xl p-4 font-sans font-black tracking-widest hover:text-dark-green rounded-3xl'
      whileHover={{ scale: 0.98 }}
      whileTap={{ scale: 0.95 }}
      variants={itemVariants}
    >
      Work
    </motion.li>
    <motion.li
      className='w-56 bg-silver text-black  flex items-center justify-center relative text-2xl md:text-3xl xl:text-4xl p-4 font-sans font-black tracking-widest hover:text-dark-green rounded-3xl'
      whileHover={{ scale: 0.98 }}
      whileTap={{ scale: 0.95 }}
      variants={itemVariants}
    >
      About
    </motion.li>
    <motion.li
      className='w-56 bg-silver text-black  flex items-center justify-center relative text-2xl md:text-3xl xl:text-4xl p-4 font-sans font-black tracking-widest hover:text-dark-green rounded-3xl'
      whileHover={{ scale: 0.98 }}
      whileTap={{ scale: 0.95 }}
      variants={itemVariants}
    >
      Contact
    </motion.li>
  </motion.ul>
</nav>
```

Variants -

```
  const sentence = {
    hidden: { opacity: 0 },
    visible: {
      opacity: 1,
      transition: {
        delay: 0.2,
        staggerChildren: 0.05,
      },
    },
  };

  const letter = {
    hidden: { opacity: 0 },
    visible: {
      opacity: 1,
      transition: { duration: 0.5, ease: 'easeInOut' },
    },
  };

  const containerVariants = {
    hidden: { opacity: 1 },
    visible: {
      opacity: 1,
      transition: {
        staggerChildren: 0.5,
      },
    },
  };

  const itemVariants = {
    hidden: { opacity: 0 },
    visible: {
      opacity: 1,
      transition: { duration: 2, ease: 'easeInOut' },
    },
  };
```